# R programming - counting the occurrence of a certain range of numbers

Tags: r, count, range

Can you guys help get the 'counts' of particular ranges. For example, I want to know how many times a score of 0.5 to 1, 1 to 1.5, 2.0 to 2.5 occurred etc. I have a sample data below.

```
  Times Scores
    0   0.6
    1.2 0.5
    1.8 1.2
    2.4 1.4
    3   1.5
    3.6 2
    4.2 0.5
    4.8 0.6
    5.4 0.4
    6   1
    6.6 1.1
    8   0.6
    9.4 1.5
    10.8    1.5
    12.2    1.3
    13.6    1.6
    15  1.4
    16.4    1.2
    17.8    1.4
    19.2    2.6
    20.6    2
    22  2.2
    23.4    2.4
    24.8    1.4
    26.2    1.2
    27.6    0.5
    29  0.8
    30.4    1.4
    31.8    1.6
    33.2    2.2
    34.6    2.5
    36  3.6
    37.4    3.78
    38.8    2.5
    40.2    3.5
    41.6    3.4
    43  3.5
    44.4    3.3
    45.8    2.1
    47.2    2.3
    48.6    0.6
    50  0.7
    51.4    0.8
    52.8    1.4
    54.2    1.5
    55.6    1.6
    57  1.5
    58.4    1.2
    59.8    1.1
    61.2    1.56
    62.6    2.02
    64  2.48
    65.4    2.94
    66.8    3.4
    68.2    2.1
    69.6    2.8
    71  3.9
    72.4    2.3
    73.8    2.4
    75.2    5.5
    76.6    4.6
    78  1.2
    79.4    1.3
    80.8    1.4
    82.2    1.8
    83.6    0.5
    85  0.2
    86.4    0.3
    87.8    0.6
    89.2    0.4
    90.6    0.5
    92  0.6
    93.4    1.06
    94.8    1.52
    96.2    1.98
    97.6    2.44
    99  2.9
    100.4   3.36
    101.8   3.82
    103.2   0.6
    104.6   0.5
    106 1.2
    107.4   1.4
    108.8   1.5
    110.2   2
    111.6   0.5
    113 0.6
    114.4   0.4
    115.8   1
    117.2   1.1
    118.6   0.6
    120 1.5
    121.4   1.5
    122.8   1.3
    124.2   1.76
    125.6   2.22
    127 2.68
    128.4   3.14
    129.8   3.6
    131.2   4.06
    132.6   4.52
    134 4.98
    135.4   5.44
    136.8   5.9
    138.2   6.36
    139.6   6.82
    141 0.6
    142.4   0.5
    143.8   1.2
    145.2   1.4
    146.6   1.5
    148 2
    149.4   0.5
    150.8   0.6
    152.2   0.4
    153.6   1
    155 1.1
    156.4   0.6
    157.8   1.5
    159.2   1.5
    160.6   1.3
    162 1.76
    163.4   2.22
    164.8   2.68
    166.2   3.5
    167.6   3.3
    169 2.1
    170.4   2.3
    171.8   0.6
    173.2   0.7
    174.6   0.8
    176 1.4
    177.4   1.5
    178.8   1.6
    180.2   1.5
    181.6   1.2
    183 1.1
    184.4   0.5
    185.8   0.6
    187.2   0.1
    188.6   0.8
    190 0.5
    191.4   0.6
    192.8   0.3
    194.2   0.5
    195.6   1.5
    197 1.8
    198.4   2
    199.8   2.2
```

I wanted to separate my 'Times' columns into 15 bin intervals which I could do. The code that I used is the one below

```
Data = cut(Sampledata$Times, seq(0,200, by=15), right=FALSE)
finaldata <- by(Sampledata, Data, FUN=I)
```

But now I want to know how to get the counts of different Score ranges for each 15 bin interval
The score ranges that I want are : 0.5 to 1, 1 to 1.5, 2.0 to 2.5  for each 15 bin interval

Thanks guys...any suggestion will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution using , `by`  as you have tried to do , but I replace identity function by a custom one. For each Time interval, I use `cut` to  divides the range of scores into intervals and use `tapply` to compute the length of each score interval. The all is transformed to a matrix using `rbind.`

```
do.call(rbind,by(Sampledata, Data, FUN=function(x){
  tapply(x$Scores,
         cut(x$Scores,c( 0.5,1,1.5, 2.0 ,2.5)),
          length)
}))

         (0.5,1] (1,1.5] (1.5,2] (2,2.5]
[0,15)          4       7       2      NA
[15,30)         1       5       1       2
[30,45)        NA       1       1       3
[45,60)         3       5       1       2
[60,75)        NA      NA       1       5
[75,90)         1       3       1      NA
[90,105)        2       1       2       1
[105,120)       3       4       1      NA
[120,135)      NA       3       1       1
[135,150)       1       3       1      NA
[150,165)       3       4       1       1
[165,180)       3       2       1       2
[180,195)       3       3      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, here is a simple solution:

`table(cut(YOURDATA, breaks = seq.int(from = 0.5, to = 2.5, by = 0.5)))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want and it's not so easy to read your data to R but the concept should be:

Let's assume `data` contains your numbers and `U` is a vector of your intervals, then

```
set.seed(123);
data <- rnorm(1e3);
U <- c(0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5);
counts <- numeric(length(U)-1);
for(i in 1:length(counts)) {
    counts[i] <- length(which(data>=U[i] & data<U[i+1]));
}

counts
[1] 146  83  46  22
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a boolean vector like this :

```
a<-rep(F,length(Scores))
for (j in 1:length(Scores))
{
    if(0.5<Scores[j] && 1>=Scores[j])
a[j]<-T
}
```

And use the function sum() to count the times when it's true :

```
nb0.5to1<-sum(a)
```

And do the same for the others intervalls. The function seq() may use if you don't want to repeat each time the definition.